# Why do list(range(50)) and range(50) have different memory sizes in Python despite being equal?

Tags: python

I just tested out my system's memory and noticed something:

Python 2:

```
from sys import getsizeof
x1 = range(50)
x2 = list(range(50))
getsizeof(x1) #472
getsizeof(x2) #568
x1==x2 #True
```

Python 3:

```
from sys import getsizeof
x1 = [x for x in range(50)]
x2 = list([x for x in range(50)])
getsizeof(x1) #528
getsizeof(x2) #560
x1==x2 #True
```

If I nest more `list()` functions around x2, it is still the same as just one.